# Scrollbar on select list in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have two drop downs in a search box, a "YearFrom" and a "YearTo".

When nothing has been selected in the "YearFrom", the "YearTo" box looks a little like this :

[image]

However the functionality is that once a "YearFrom" is selected, that the "YearTo" fields only offer what is available AFTER the year from. In essence, we end up with HTML like this :

```
<select>
<option value="">Any</option>
<option value="1950" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">1950</option>
<option value="1960" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">1960</option>
...
<option value="2011" style="">2011</option>
<option value="2012" style="">2012</option>
<option value="2013" style="">2013</option>
</select>
```

So any years below the YearFrom value are hidden. However what we then end up with is the select list looking like this :

[image]

So it isn't so much as a drop down, as now a tiny little box with a scroller on the right.

For reference, this doesn't happen in any other browser. e.g. this is how it looks in Firefox.

[image]

Comment: try setting a fixed height for your drop downs

Comment: Do you mean something like... <select style="height:100px">? That doesn't work unfortunately. Just makes the selected option massive.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this error as well.

My guess is that the Chrome browser calculates the drop-down height by measuring the heigths of the options and optgroups, but stops calculating the moment it comes across an element that has no height or is display:none.

To work around this in my own code, I dynamically rearrange the options after each update so that display:none elements are at the bottom of the list. it creates another visual bug (white space on right of dropdown) but I can live with that one.